# ZeroMQ threw ZMQError on socket bind to an ipc:// protocol address (python)

Tags: python, sockets, ipc, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm trying to use the IPC protocol with ZeroMQ in Python.

```py
import sys
import time

from random import randint

import zmq

def main(url=None):
    ctx = zmq.Context.instance()
    publisher = ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
    if url:
        publisher.bind(url)
    else:
        publisher.bind('ipc://var/run/fast-service')
    # Ensure subscriber connection has time to complete
    time.sleep(1)

    # Send out all 1,000 topic messages
    for topic_nbr in range(1000):
        publisher.send_multipart([
            b"%03d" % topic_nbr,
            b"Save Roger",
        ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else None)
```

It gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pathopub.py", line 43, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else None)
  File "pathopub.py", line 19, in main
    publisher.bind("ipc://var/run/fast-service")
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 547, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.bind
zmq.error.ZMQError: No such file or directory for ipc path "var/run/fast-service".
```

I don't understand why would this happen with the `socket.bind()` function, since in the [documentation](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-ipc) it says:

> *When binding a socket to a local address using `zmq_bind()` with the ipc transport, the endpoint shall be interpreted as an arbitrary string identifying the pathname to create.*

which means that it is not necessary to supply an already created directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL scheme is `ipc://`. You need to add an absolute path `/var/run/fast-service`. So,

```
publisher.bind('ipc:///var/run/fast-service')
```

More generally the URL is `ipc://<host>/<path>`. You want local host, so that part is empty. A file system URL is similar, `file:///home/foo/bar.txt` references `/home/foo/bar.txt` on the local host.

Comment: ohhh. I get it. I ran again my code and it gives
`
zmq.error.ZMQError: Permission denied
`

Comment: You likely don't have permissions there. Try `ipc://tmp/fast-service` as a test. You may want to put it somewhere where a group has visibility if you don't want it open to all.